# Monaco editor get access to AST

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using monaco editor for typescript. Is there a way to get an AST for the current model? Is it possible to modify the tree so the editor will react to the changes? I.e I would like to do simple refactoring tool for typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Monaco does not expose its AST, but you can use [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift) instead:

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(
     document.querySelector("#editor"), {value: 'var foo;'})// editor content: var foo;
const newValue = jscodeshift(editor.getValue())
     .findVariableDeclarators('foo')
     .renameTo('bar')
     .toSource();
editor.setValue(newValue); // editor content: var bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something related: i'm using monaco the edit TypeScript code based on Compiler API but then the code actually run in the backend since typeScript compiler dont' support the browser as far as I know. https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me